# How to get hostname of the machine that the user logged in on?

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, hostname, directoryentry

I would like to get the hostname of the machine that the enduser logged into last. I am able to get the user name, and the last login with `DirectoryEntry`.

Here is my code:

```
var dirs = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://DCName");
foreach (DirectoryEntry de in dirs.Children)
{
    var user = string.Empty;
    var lastLogin = string.Empty;
    var lastLogoff = string.Empty;

    if (de.SchemaClassName == "User")
    {
        user = de.Name;

        if (de.Properties["lastLogin"].Value != null)
        {                        
            lastLogin = de.Properties["lastLogin"].Value.ToString();
        }
        if (de.Properties[lastLogoff].Value != null)
        {                        
            lastLogoff = de.Properties[lastLogoff].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the hostname as well? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Directly, no, that information is not stored with the user in the Active Directory.

However what you want is still possible, if you want to accomplish this you will need to enable [Audit Logon Events](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787567(v=ws.10).aspx) on the domain controller, this will record logon events in the event log similar to<sup>1</sup>

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:  SYSTEM
    Account Name:  WIN-R9H529RIO4Y$
    Account Domain:  WORKGROUP
    Logon ID:  0x3e7
Logon Type:10
New Logon:
       Security ID:  WIN-R9H529RIO4Y\Administrator
    Account Name:  Administrator
    Account Domain:  WIN-R9H529RIO4Y
    Logon ID:  0x19f4c
    Logon GUID:  {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Process Information:
   Process ID:  0x4c0
    Process Name:  C:\Windows\System32\winlogon.exe
Network Information:
     Workstation Name: WIN-R9H529RIO4Y
    Source Network Address: 10.42.42.211
    Source Port:  1181
Detailed Authentication Information:
     Logon Process:  User32 
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
   Package Name (NTLM only): -
   Key Length:  0
```

You can then read the event log from the domain controller in your program and that log can be parsed out getting the user who logged in (`Account Name`) and where he logged in to (`Workstation Name`). Just use the `lastLogin` you got from your example code to get the approximate time to search the event log for the login audit event.

---

**EDIT:** For some other alternative solutions see [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/44862/best-way-to-find-the-computer-a-user-last-logged-on-from), most answers are a variation of "have a login script that runs and records the computer it was run on some place".

---

<sup>1: Example log taken from https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624</sup>

Comment: That is an interesting way of going about it. I was hoping there would be done in a easier way.

Comment: The easier way is the login script method shown on the Server Fault question. Other than that, you really don't have options.